# Izpack condition not working

Tags: java, conditional-statements, izpack

I have the following condition defined in my install.xml.

```
<conditions>
    <condition type="contains" id="which.java">
        <variable>$SYSTEM_java_version</variable>
        <value>1.6</value>
    </condition>
</conditions>
```

And I have this file which I only want to install if the JRE version is 1.6.

```
<file src="Releases/Other/Instalador/JCEUnlimitedCrypto/JRE6/local_policy.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" condition="which.java"/>
```

But it never installs this file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In common, you got to cut off the '$' from the variable name, like this:

```
<conditions>
    <condition type="contains" id="which.java">
        <variable>variable</variable>
        <value>1.6</value>
    </condition>
</conditions>
```

In this case, this won't probably work, because for this case there is not done the special resolution of variables with the SYSTEM_ prefix.

If you want to check it over a variable you have to map this first to a regular IzPack variable, like this:

```
<variables>
  <variable name="java.version" value="${SYSTEM_java_version}"/>
</variables>

<conditions>
    <condition type="contains" id="which.java">
        <variable>java.version</variable>
        <value>1.6</value>
    </condition>
</conditions>
```

An easier approach is this one, which uses the regular IzPack variable resolver:

```
<conditions>
    <condition type="contains" id="which.java">
        <string>${SYSTEM_java_version}</string>
        <value>1.6</value>
    </condition>
</conditions>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<condition type="compareversions" id="isValidJavaVersion">
     <arg1>${previous.wrapper.java.version}</arg1>
     <arg2>1.6</arg2>
     <operator>lt</operator>
</condition>
```

YOu can refer also to this link [here](https://izpack.atlassian.net/wiki/display/IZPACK/CompareVersions+Condition)